# CSS bug on label element in in form when validation labels are displayed

Tags: css

The labels at the left hand side of my form such as '**Name** Add your name' seem to move position when I click on the send button and the red validation messages are displayed.

The form is found here:

http://www.bestclownintown.co.uk/book.php

Here is the CSS rule for the label and the second rule is for the error message. Is there anyway to revise these CSS rules or the rules of other elements to ensure that when 'send' is clicked the black labels display on the left, and red validation labels on the right of the form.

```
#stylized label {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
width: 140px;
float: left;
}

label.error {  
color: red; 
padding-left: .5em; 
vertical-align: top; 
}
```

Comment: Did you change the content of link given in question??? Now it is completely shattered but it was coming properly just before 2 minutes.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am no longer making any changes, as it will disrupt anyone trying to assess it like yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following changes.

- Change the width of your form from 500px to 900px so that it will accommodate label,input and error message.
- Add clear: both; to left side Labels.
- Remove padding-left for error messages.
- Add height:40px to error messages.

All the styles are defined in style.css. So check for that classes used for above changes and  do the required changes in that file.

Please let me know if any issue if left.

Comment: Thank you Rain I have done what you have asked. The site now looks like - http://www.bestclownintown.co.uk/book.php

We are getting there, though the validation messages and button now appear in strange places when 'send' is clicked.

Comment: Instead of clear: both; in #stylized label.error
use
clear: right;

Let me know if the issue is still there.

Comment: Thank you again for your time Rain, you have been very helpful and my form now appears as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the exact same css to the original labels and to the error labels,
as they are both a match for #stylized label

You should add a class to each label.
Alternatively you can write specific style for the error label, such as:

```
#stylized label {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
width: 140px;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

#stylized label.error {  
color: red; 
padding-left: 140px; 
vertical-align: top;
float: left; 
}
```

That might tidy things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

the solution that [puppybeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343067/puppybeard) has post is appropriate.

though if you want/need your validations to display on right side then you might need to edit your code a bit.

float create some problems in IE browsers. use it only when you want extreme left or right position. you can use..

```
display:inline-block;
```

use,

```
*display:inline-block; (for ie-7/8)
```

Comment: Razor, I have edited and applied this rule, but still the validation messages appear underneath and not the right side. Is there something I am missing when I am inspecting my code?

Comment: your design is little scattered in terms of dom hierarchy. form is taking limited width which compresses your elements and shifting validation error labels underneath elements. Remove float from every control because as i see your design it seems not necessary. try working on it i hope you will find good results :)